# Eliminate NULL check in Searching linked List

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, while-loop, linked-list

How do I eliminate the NULL check in every iteration of the while-loop searching a linked list?

Comment: What language are you using?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why do you want to eliminate it? How will you know when you have reached the end of the list?

Comment: I just need an idea from algorithms perspective. Anyway you can consider c++ language.

Comment: @hammat thats what i am asking is there a way to do this type of thing through some other technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a sentinel element - append the element you search. If you found the sentinel return not found; remove the sentinel in both cases.

Added:

See [Sentinel search example](http://pluto.ksi.edu/~fthulin/310mod3.html); my apology for the language. I remembered the strategy from [N. Wirth's "Algorithmen und Datenstrukturen"](http://books.google.de/books?id=YdB-bGA6Zn4C&pg=PA204&lpg=PA204&dq=wirth%20sentinel%20search&source=bl&ots=a6R7XEfvJU&sig=1iT4ot3E4PxIEYr2T4xqAJzJ1BQ&hl=de&ei=ePbKTfreOoPesgazudmQAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false); my apologies for the languages.

Comment: Even in this way we have to check for sentinel in every iteration and aslo to check the value of the element which we are searching. Whats the gain that we are getting

Comment: Without a sentinel you have to first check for next==NULL, then dereference the next pointer and test for your search value. With a sentinel you can skip the test for NULL, dereference the next pointer and then test for your search value or special sentinel value. It's slightly more succinct and perhaps slightly more efficient, but in most cases probably not worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't.

As long as you are iterating over any data structure, you always want your algorithm to act differently IF it has reached the end of the structure thus requiring any kind of check. That is true whatever your data structure is and does not depend on the "way" you are iterating: for(int i = 0 ; **i < sizeArray** ; ++i), for(iterator it = myList.begin() ; **it != mylist.end()**; it++), while(**currentNode.hasChildren()**), while(**javaIterator.hasNext()**) ...

Nevertheless, whatever your loop does, checking if an accessible object is NULL will never be the bottleneck of your algorithm. It is even difficult to do less time consuming...

The ONLY way you could possibly avoid the check would be to avoid the loop itself, therefore writing each step underlying in the loop but it requires you to know the size of the linked list at compile time and in that case your compiler may have optimized your code better than you would probably have done yourself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a circular (looping) linked list where the last element is linked with the first one.

Comment: You've just replaced a NULL check with an is-this-the-first-element-again test.

Comment: Yep, but there has to be a method to stop. Still NULL check is eliminated.

Comment: Yes, of course. But replacing one test with another hasn't gained you much.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of the number of elements in your list. If you always know how many element are in the list and at which position you currently are, then there is no need to check for `NULL` when you want to advance to the next element.

Comment: that means to in/decrement a counter and an extra compare.

Comment: @Ekkehard: Of course, but it's a different technique to solve this problem, which seems to be what the OP is asking for. If the goal of the question was optimized performance, the best answer would probably be "don't use a linked list".